JS Canvas - My clicked positions work on desktop, but aren't working properly on touchscreens
I'm doing a project, learning canvas.
My basic operations work (dragging mouse over the canvas to draw, clearing)
but when I switch to touch, it draws offset, like diagonally down and right from where im clicking
here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/Dolevy97/pen/ExzwaLe
and the relevant lines of code:

function onMove(ev) {
    if (!gIsDrawing) return

    gCtx.fillStyle = gBackgroundColor
    gCtx.strokeStyle = gShape.color
    gCtx.lineWidth = gShape.size

    const pos = getEvPos(ev)
    //* Calc the delta, the diff we moved
    const dx = pos.x - gPrevPos.x
    const dy = pos.y - gPrevPos.y
    move(dx, dy)
    gCtx.fillStyle = gBackgroundColor

    if (gShape.shape === 'pen') {
        gCtx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y)
        gCtx.stroke()
    } else if (gShape.shape === 'square') {
        gCtx.strokeRect(pos.x, pos.y, 50, 50)
        gCtx.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, 50, 50)
    } else if (gShape.shape === 'triangle') {
        gCtx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y)
        gCtx.lineTo(pos.x + 80, pos.y + 80)
        gCtx.lineTo(pos.x - 20, pos.y + 100)
        gCtx.closePath()
        gCtx.fill()
        gCtx.stroke()
    } else if (gShape.shape === 'circle') {
        gCtx.beginPath()
        gCtx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, gShape.size * 10, 0, Math.PI * 2)
        gCtx.fill()
        gCtx.stroke()
    }

    //* Save the last pos, we remember where we`ve been and move accordingly
    gPrevPos = pos
}

function getEvPos(ev) {

    let pos = {
        x: ev.offsetX,
        y: ev.offsetY,
    }

    if (TOUCH_EVS.includes(ev.type)) {
        ev.preventDefault()
        ev = ev.changedTouches[0]
        pos = {
            x: ev.pageX - ev.target.offsetLeft - ev.target.clientLeft,
            y: ev.pageY - ev.target.offsetTop - ev.target.clientTop
        }
    }

    return pos
}


I can't understand what's not working because it seems that it works for others with the same getEvPos.
Thank you!
I tried playing around with it, but to my understanding, the calculations in getEvPos are constant and shouldn't be touched. So it's probably something in my 'onMove'

Why did you switch from using .offsetX to using pageX? .offsetX is what you want.

@RayWallace Where specifically?

Sorry, ignore that comment, I didn't read the code carefully enough.

You can use getBoundingClientRect on your target to subtract the target's left and top offset from your page coordinates. For example:
if (TOUCH_EVS.includes(ev.type)) {
  ev.preventDefault()
  ev = ev.changedTouches[0]
  const { left, top } = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect()
  pos = {
    x: ev.pageX - left,
    y: ev.pageY - top
  }
}

In a runnable example: (For those not on a touch device: you can open dev tools, go to Sensors and set Touch to force enabled to see it in action)


'use strict'

var gBackgroundColor = '#ececec'

var gElCanvas
var gCtx
var gPrevPos

const TOUCH_EVS = ['touchstart', 'touchmove', 'touchend']

function onInit() {
    gElCanvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
    gCtx = gElCanvas.getContext('2d')
    addListeners()
    resizeCanvas()
    renderCanvas()
}

function renderCanvas() {
    gCtx.fillStyle = gBackgroundColor
    gCtx.fillRect(0, 0, gElCanvas.width, gElCanvas.height)
    createDrawing()
}

// CHANGE CANVAS LOOK/SHAPE

function changeColor(ev) {
    gShape.color = ev.target.value
}

function changeBackgroundColor(ev) {
    gBackgroundColor = ev.target.value
    renderCanvas()
}

function setShape(ev) {
    var currValue = ev.target.value
    switch (currValue) {
        case 'squares':
            gShape.shape = 'square'
            break;

        case 'triangles':
            gShape.shape = 'triangle'
            break;

        case 'circles':
            gShape.shape = 'circle'
            break;

        case 'pen':
            gShape.shape = 'pen'
            break;
    }
}

function resizeCanvas() {
    const elContainer = document.querySelector('.canvas-container')
    gElCanvas.width = elContainer.clientWidth - 100
    gElCanvas.height = elContainer.clientHeight - 200
}


// MOUSE / TOUCH CONTROL

function onDown(ev) {
    gIsDrawing = true
    const pos = getEvPos(ev)
    gShape.pos = pos
    gPrevPos = pos
}

function onMove(ev) {
    if (!gIsDrawing) return

    gCtx.fillStyle = gBackgroundColor
    gCtx.strokeStyle = gShape.color
    gCtx.lineWidth = gShape.size

    const pos = getEvPos(ev)
    //* Calc the delta, the diff we moved
    const dx = pos.x - gPrevPos.x
    const dy = pos.y - gPrevPos.y
    move(dx, dy)
    gCtx.fillStyle = gBackgroundColor

    if (gShape.shape === 'pen') {
        gCtx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y)
        gCtx.stroke()
    } else if (gShape.shape === 'square') {
        gCtx.strokeRect(pos.x, pos.y, 50, 50)
        gCtx.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, 50, 50)
    } else if (gShape.shape === 'triangle') {
        gCtx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y)
        gCtx.lineTo(pos.x + 80, pos.y + 80)
        gCtx.lineTo(pos.x - 20, pos.y + 100)
        gCtx.closePath()
        gCtx.fill()
        gCtx.stroke()
    } else if (gShape.shape === 'circle') {
        gCtx.beginPath()
        gCtx.arc(pos.x, pos.y, gShape.size * 10, 0, Math.PI * 2)
        gCtx.fill()
        gCtx.stroke()
    }

    //* Save the last pos, we remember where we`ve been and move accordingly
    gPrevPos = pos
}

function onUp() {
    gIsDrawing = false
    gCtx.beginPath()
}

function getEvPos(ev) {

    let pos = {
        x: ev.offsetX,
        y: ev.offsetY,
    }
    
    if (TOUCH_EVS.includes(ev.type)) {
        ev.preventDefault()
        ev = ev.changedTouches[0]
        const { left, top } = ev.target.getBoundingClientRect()
        pos = {
            x: ev.pageX - left,
            y: ev.pageY - top
        }
    }

    return pos
}

//SAVE / CLEAR / ABOUT

function onClearCanvas() {
    gCtx.clearRect(0, 0, gElCanvas.width, gElCanvas.height);
}

// EVENT LISTENERS

function addListeners() {
    addMouseListeners()
    addTouchListeners()

    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        resizeCanvas()
    })
}

function addMouseListeners() {
    gElCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onDown)
    gElCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMove)
    gElCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onUp)
}

function addTouchListeners() {
    gElCanvas.addEventListener('touchstart', onDown)
    gElCanvas.addEventListener('touchmove', onMove)
    gElCanvas.addEventListener('touchend', onUp)
}

//Diff file - service

var gShape

var gIsDrawing = false

function createDrawing(pos = { x: 0, y: 0 }) {
    gShape = {
        pos,
        size: 2,
        color: '#000000',
        shape: 'pen',
    }
}

function getShape() {
    return gShape
}

function move(dx, dy) {
    gShape.pos.x += dx
    gShape.pos.y += dy
}
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.canvas-container {
    position: relative;

    width: 80vw;
    height: 70vh;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin: auto;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    border: 1px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 0.5);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px 1px black;
}


.tool-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    
    border: 1px solid rgb(0 0 0 / 0.3);
}

.tool-items {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 15px;

    list-style-type: none;
    padding-inline: 20px;
}

.tool-items:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=color] {
    width: 27px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

canvas {
    background-color: #ececec;
}
<body onload="onInit()">
<h1>Mr. Canvas</h1>
    <div class="canvas-container">
        <div class="tool-bar">
            <ul class="tool-items">
                <li><input onchange="changeBackgroundColor(event)" type="color" name="color" value="#ececec"></li>
                <li><input onchange="changeColor(event)" type="color" name="bgcolor"></li>
                <li><select name="shape" onchange="setShape(event)">
                    <option value="pen">PEN</option>
                    <option value="squares">SQUARES</option>
                    <option value="triangles">TRIANGLES</option>
                    <option value="circles">CIRCLES</option>
                </select></li>
                <li><button onclick="">Save</button></li>
                <li><button onclick="onClearCanvas()">Clear</button></li>
                <li><button onclick="onAbout()">About</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <canvas width="450" height="450"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script src="js/service.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



